# How can I limit Asterisk's Chanspy feature to certain channels?

Tags: voip, asterisk, freepbx

I'm using a standard config of Asterisk 1.4 with FreePBX using the chanspy feature code. I want to restrict what channels it is possible to spy on, ideally doing this in a .conf file. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can do this by password protecting the feature, here is an example:

http://www.fonality.com/trixbox/forums/trixbox-forums/open-discussion/password-protecting-feature-codes

From the page:

```
Here's how it works - you pick up the phone and dial 555 (Channel Spy Feature Code), The system will ask for a password. If the correct password is entered spying ensues. IF the incorrect password is entered three times the call is dropped. All I did was add a couple of lines to extensions_custom.conf

;Password Protect Channel Spy
exten => 555,1,Authenticate(1234)

;Password Protect ZapBarge
exten => 888,1,Authenticate(1234)
```